# Is it possible to configure embedded cassandra instance using properties file not the storage-conf.xml?

Tags: properties, cassandra

I'm lunching cassandra in embedded mode and want to configure seeds for its nodes in .property file. By default cassandra config contained in storage-conf.xml.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.